# Error exporting a large file to Excel from SSRS on SQL Server 2016 (Power BI Server)

Tags: sql-server, excel, reporting-services, export-to-excel, power-bi-report-server

I have a paginated report on the server that is run for my book of business and non-bob numbers. It has a fairly efficient query, the non-bob numbers execute and export to Excel pretty fast - but when bob is run, it takes over 2 hours and the execution crashes when it is exporting.

If run with a Subscription export to Excel, the error reads **"Failure writing file [REPORT NAME]: An error has occurred during report processing."**, but there are no specific error messages in the logs.

The following errors show up in log at the end of the execution:

> OData exception occurred: System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle
>   has been closed
>
> ERROR: Throwing
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException:
>   Missing static reference,
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException:
>   An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for
>   more details.;
>
> ERROR: An exception has occurred in data set 'Source'. Details:
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException:
>   An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for
>   more details. INFO: DataPrefetch abort handler called for Report with
>   ID=. Aborting data sources ...
>
> ERROR: Throwing
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException:
>   [AbnormalTermination:ReportProcessing],
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException:
>   An error has occurred during report processing. --->
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException:
>   An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for
>   more details.

And I am not sure where the other mentioned error logs are to dive into this.

The query takes less than 5 minutes to pull a few million records, then I slice these records in 10 different summary tablix using SSRS with the goal of exporting the output to Excel (EXCELOPENXML).

There are 52 columns per exported Tab, and no more than 25,000 records in the largest tab, so the output does not hit any Excel limitations. There are no string fields except for grouping names, which do no exceed more than 50 characters, everything else is a number or percentage. There are small charts in each tablix row.

I expect the final output file size to be big, maybe more than 50 mb. However, I have not come across any documentation on the output file size limits in Excel.

I tried adjusting timeout (to unlimited) and increasing memory sizes in report and subscription options, `web.config` and `rsreportserver.config` having the service restarted, but that didn't help with the execution.

Comment: While that may not be a technical limitation of Excel... a 50mb Excel file is generally unwieldy for most use cases, imo. Aside from that, have you looked at the server logs or SSRS log file for the details? That might help.

Comment: The report itself is manageable for consumption, in our situation there a lot of very large Excel files, not that I agree with it, but it is what it is. As far as logs, yes, as I mentioned in the description, however, I can't locate the log file that these logs are referring to.

Comment: what growth did you have of this file at the last successful output? i.e. what was the file size or row count? PS: you can follow this resource for detail on accessing the error logs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/reporting-services-log-files-and-sources?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: One of the groupings, which is smaller than BOB was about 50 mb already, BOB would be at least that. Unfortunately, this page points to the ReportServer, mine is a PowerBI Report Server, and I located the logs here (where I got some of the error messages): ...\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Report Server\SERVER\LogFiles